# Security Incident Response Tracking

Tags: incident-response, siem, soc

Besides Security IR tracking & workflow that is available in SIEM platforms, what are other tools that can do this such as standalone products like ServiceNow SIR or Everbridge xmatters? I found Resolver and RTIR but don't know anything about either. Any others? Thoughts on these tools or others in terms of effectiveness and vendor support?

I recently found that Splunk Enterprise Security does not support a least privilege model and that anyone that has access to incidents can view ***all*** incidents. I am looking for a solution that is more granular and can be siloed to smaller teams.

**My search through older posts**

- This post is a bit outdated and some of the tools no longer exist (or
  at least the links are broken):

[Security Operation Center (SOC)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/security-operation-center-soc)

- This post was answered with obsolete tools:

[Enterprise security incident response and detection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/enterprise-security-incident-response-and-detection)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for products/services are now off-topic, because, as you've seen, they don't age well.